# How to map user name to each comment

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have three different models with association

**user.rb**

```
has_many :products
has_many :comments
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
```

**Product.rb**

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user

def product_comments_object
   comments_object = self.comments.all.select(:id,:user_id,:comment)
   {comments: comments_object}
end
```

Now, I'm getting the `comments_object` like:

```
"comments": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "comment": "comment number 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "comment": "comment number 2"
  }
]
```

But how to get `user_name` in-place of `user_id`. I tried using `map` but didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to parse comment objects to get user name . parse each comment object and call `parse_comment` method which return a hash with user name.

```
def product_comments_object
  comments_object = []
  self.comments.each do |comment| 
    comments_object << parse_comment(comment)
  end
  {comments: comments_object}
end

def parse_comment comment
  {id: comment.id, user_name: comment.user.name, comment: "comment number 1"}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do a little Ruby mapping.

Check out the following:

```
def product_comments_object
   comments = Product.joins(comment: :user).where("products.id is ?", self.id).select("comments.id as id, comments.comment as comment, users.name as name")

   comments_object = map_object(comments)
   {comments: comments_object}
end

def map_object(comments)
   c_o = []
   comments.each do |row|
     c_o << {
       "id" => row.id,
       "name" => row.name,
       "comment" => row.comment
     }
   end
   c_o
end
```

I think this should work well for you...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  def product_comments_object
    comments_object = self.comments.all.joins('users')
                          .where('users.id = comments.user_id')
                          .select('comments.id, users.name AS user_name, comments.comment')
    { comments: comments_object }
  end
```